# How to insert into two different tables a single select?

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have 3 tables. One is my players table, a history table and a item table.

I need to check for each player of the players table if they already are in the history table, if not i need to insert then into history table and give then one item on the item table (another insert).

I already got this code but i don't know how to run two different inserts for one select , i searched all along but maybe i should use IF and THEN?

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO tb_item (player_id, friend_id, item_id)
SELECT 1, id, 101 FROM tb_player 
WHERE vip = 1 
AND creation_date BETWEEN now() - INTERVAL '2 year' AND now() - INTERVAL '1 years'
AND id NOT IN (  SELECT ig.player_id FROM tb_history ig WHERE ig.item_id = 101
```

Comment: I've never used Postgress but this sound like a job for a Stored Procedure

Comment: I have a hard time understanding what you want. Please [edit] your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. _Formatted_ text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) It sounds as if a writeable CTE is what you are looking for: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING

Answer (score 1):

You can insert using [Common Table Expressions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html) like this

```
WITH inserted_item AS (
  INSERT INTO tb_item (player_id, friend_id, item_id)
  SELECT 1, id, 101 FROM tb_player 
  WHERE vip = 1 
    AND creation_date BETWEEN now() - INTERVAL '2 year' 
    AND now() - INTERVAL '1 years'
    AND id NOT IN (
        SELECT ig.player_id FROM tb_history ig WHERE ig.item_id = 101
    )
  RETURNING *
)
INSERT INTO tb_history (some_col1, some_col2, some_col3)
SELECT player_id, friend_id, item_id
FROM inserted_item
```

Answer (score 0):

You can´t do that, you must use two insert statment, other way to make it , by using trigger for the table when insert in first table will insert to the second table automatically (but also another insert statement)

Comment: I guess it's fine to use 2 insert statement but i dont want to select the tb_player twice for the same thing, i just want to check if it should be inserted then insert in those two tables, isnt there a way?

Comment: You can use temp table to but the result on temp table and then make two insert to the 2 destination tables, this recommended when the SQL is slow or the SQL can return diferent result when call the second time, in this case it´s 3 insert statement.